# What is the difference between evolutionary programming and genetic programming?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, computer-science, evolutionary-algorithm, genetic-programming

What is the difference between evolutionary programming and genetic programming? In which circumstances is it better to use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple difference is genetic programming is a class of evolutionary programming.

**[Genetic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming)** use crossover and mutation to search the space of possible solutions.

> In artificial intelligence, genetic programming (GP) is an
>   evolutionary algorithm-based methodology inspired by biological
>   evolution to find computer programs that perform a user-defined task.

**[Evolutionary programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_programming)** mainly uses mutation.

> Evolutionary programming is one of the four major evolutionary
>   algorithm paradigms. It is similar to genetic programming, but the
>   structure of the program to be optimized is fixed, while its numerical
>   parameters are allowed to evolve.

Check this [tutorial](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://www.tech.dmu.ac.uk/~mgongora/comp5232/EvolProg_Intro.pdf&ei=yLo9UqfeDI_QrQfiloCABQ&usg=AFQjCNEJqb-pIgwyIzYcl54rdEYDg5tjJg&sig2=MFhRdUkgED-GnGOFw4D-CA&bvm=bv.52434380,d.bmk) for details.

> In what instances is it better to use one over the other

There are certain application areas where you can use both of them:-

**Application areas of Evolutionary programming**

- traffic routing and planning
- pharmaceutical design
- epidemiology
- cancer detection
- military planning
- control systems
- system identification
- signal processing
- learning in games

**Application areas of Genetic programming**

Check this [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_genetic_algorithm_applications)